# jquery: remove the pointer cursor?

Tags: jquery, css, preventdefault, jquery-1.9

Why can't I change the CSS of an `a` tag with jquery? For instance,

html,

```
<a href="#">1</a>
<a href="">2</a>
<a href="http://website.com/#/home/about/">3</a>
<a href="http://website.com/home/about/">4</a>
```

link 1 and 2 are not clickable so I want to remove the pointer cursor.

jquery,

```
$("a").click(function(e){
    if($(this).attr("href") == "#" || $(this).attr("href") == "") {
        alert("this is non-clickable");
        $(this).css({cursor:"default"});
        e.preventDefault();   
    }
    else{
        alert($(this).attr("href"));
        $(this).css({cursor:"pointer"});
        e.preventDefault();   
    }
});
```

is it possible?

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3uzY7/)

Comment: It works for me. What isn't working? What browser are you using?

Comment: I second it. It works.

Comment: @joespina Firefox shows `cursor: pointer;` in the fiddle he has shared :)

Comment: @Mr.Alien really? tested it right now on FF 22.0 and it works . . odd

Comment: @joespina quiet indeed, it shows me a hand when I hover 1 and 2 links :-/

Comment: @Mr.Alien well its the default after you click on it. At the start its a pointer, but after clicking on the 1/2 link it changes to the default.

Comment: @joespina yes, that's the thing he was pointing out, he wanted to avoid that pointer on hover too... IMO..

Comment: @Mr.Alien hmmm. if he wanted a jquery method of changing cursor well then his  code shouldn't use `.click` but maybe `.mouseenter` or `mouseover`. But still your `css` method is still better.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you want you can simply do this with the CSS

```
a[href="\#"], a[href=""] {
    cursor: default;
}
/* I've used an element[attr] selector here which will select all a tags 
   with this combination, if you want to target specific a tags, 
   wrap them in an element with a class and you can than refer as 
   .class a[href]... */
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/3uzY7/1/)

If you want to disable the links, you can achieve that too using CSS `pointer-events: none;` property

[**Demo 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/3uzY7/3/) (Will help you if JS is disabled, this won't alert the message, but it will help you to disable the event which you are trying to do)

Answer (score 3):

Your error is in your jquery css. You need quotes round css your js should look like this:

```
$("a").click(function(e){
    if($(this).attr("href") == "#" || $(this).attr("href") == "") {
        alert("this is non-clickable");
        $(this).css({'cursor' :"default"});
        e.preventDefault();   
    }
    else{
        alert($(this).attr("href"));
        $(this).css({'cursor':"pointer"});
        e.preventDefault();   
    }
});
```

Also you could use addClass method then in the css have a style for no href

Comment: No. The problem is not here. You don't need quotes.

Comment: Have you seen the add class

Comment: Yes and ? I don't understand why you speak about the addClass method.

Comment: You could add a class if the href is "" or "#" then have a style in css for that style of `cursor: default`

Answer (score 2):

try to change the line

from

```
$(this).css({cursor:"default"});
```

to

```
$(this).css('cursor','default');
```

let me know if you face any problem